# How to decoding the string in iphone

Tags: iphone, string, decoding

I want to decode my string. I have used parsing and get a string from RSS feed. In a string these special characters are not allowed &,<,> in my app. In server side encoding those characters and give it to the string. So now i got the string like,

```
 Actual String : <Tom&Jerry>  (only these characters are not allowed in node data & < >).

 After Encoding:  %3CTom%26Jerry%3E.
```

But i need to display the string is

```
                  <Tom&Jerry>
```

So how can i decode the string.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.iamseree.com/iphone-development/decode-html-characters-in-iphone-sdk-with-objective-c/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`-stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:).

```
[@"%3CTom%26Jerry%3E"
 stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: @Pugal: Please `NSLog(@"%@", currentString2);`

Answer (score 6):

Look for

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Or by example:

```
NSString *input = @"Hello%20World";
NSString *output = [text stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@ becomes %@",input,output);

Log: Hello%20World becomes Hello World
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer and my code is,

```
     NSString *currentString =@"%3CTom%26Jerry%3E";

     NSString  * decodeString = [currentString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    lblTitle.text = decodeString;
```

Thanks.

Comment: you could have also commented my answer instead of reposting it